# Which refers to CFI renewal based on pass rate, "activities" or "duties and responsibilities"?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, cfi

It's that time again, gotta re-up my CFI.

I always forget when I'm filling out IACRA whether CFI renewals (in the United States) based on student pass rate percentage are considered "activites" or "duties and responsibilities".

**Which of the two, "duties and responsibilites" or "activities" is the appropriate choice when submitting an IACRA application for a CFI renewal based on pass rate?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to check the **Activities** box.

The phrasing is a little weird, and it certainly doesn't line up with the regs (see [14 CFR §61.197](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div8&node=14:2.0.1.1.2.8.1.9)), but that's what you want:

> (2) Submitting a completed and signed application with the FAA and satisfactorily completing one of the following renewal requirements—
>
> (i) A record of training students showing that, during the preceding 24 calendar months, the flight instructor has endorsed at least 5 students for a practical test for a certificate or rating and at least 80 percent of those students passed that test on the first attempt.
>
> (ii) A record showing that, within the preceding 24 calendar months, the flight instructor has served as a company check pilot, chief flight instructor, company check airman, or flight instructor in a part 121 or part 135 operation, or in a position involving the regular evaluation of pilots.
>
> [...]

So, best as I can tell, that means:

- **§61.197(2)(i)** is activity - 80% pass rate on 5+ students in the preceding 24 calendar months.
- **§61.197(2)(ii)** is duties and responsibilities - serving in a position that involves standardization flights or stage checks.

---

*Disclaimer:* unfortunately, all of the AOPA material on CFI renewal is designed to get you to buy their FIRC (eyeroll), and the unhelpful [FAA IACRA document for instructors](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fiacra.faa.gov%2Fiacra_manuals%2FIACRA_Instruction_Manual_Instructor.pdf&ei=0r8wVebfIc_hoASn7YG4Bw&usg=AFQjCNENzfRBcbl3pYhlmQBn2uCuAlpo7A&sig2=O0C5YSNsUvnH4Cbm2Sa-7g) says squat as well. I'm having a hard time finding a reference that proves my interpretation, but I know it's correct!